# GDAL's CMake tooling won't accept PROJ 6.3.2 despite requiring 6.0+?

Tags: c++, cmake, gdal, proj

Expectation: build [gdal](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases) 3.7.0 C++ version using cmake, so that I can make use of it in a C++ project with VS2019.

error info: Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid.

[image]

Can I know how to build it successfully?

Here is the log detail:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30151.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30151.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at cmake/modules/Ccache.cmake:10 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.

Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:58 (include)
Performing Test test_AVX
Performing Test test_AVX - Success
Performing Test test_AVX2
Performing Test test_AVX2 - Success
Could NOT find SWIG (missing: SWIG_EXECUTABLE SWIG_DIR)
Found Python: C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/python.exe (found suitable version "3.11.3", minimum required is "3.6") found components: Interpreter Development NumPy Development.Module Development.Embed
Looking for vsnprintf
Looking for vsnprintf - not found
Looking for getcwd
Looking for getcwd - found
Looking for fcntl.h
Looking for fcntl.h - found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for locale.h
Looking for locale.h - found
Looking for xlocale.h
Looking for xlocale.h - not found
Looking for direct.h
Looking for direct.h - found
Looking for dlfcn.h
Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of int
Check size of int - done
Check size of unsigned long
Check size of unsigned long - done
Check size of long int
Check size of long int - done
Check size of void*
Check size of void* - done
Check size of size_t
Check size of size_t - done
Looking for C++ include atlbase.h
Looking for C++ include atlbase.h - found
GDAL_VERSION = 3.7.0
GDAL_ABI_FULL_VERSION = 37
GDAL_SOVERSION =
Found ODBC: odbc32.lib
Could NOT find ODBCCPP (missing: ODBCCPP_LIBRARY ODBCCPP_INCLUDE_DIR)
Could NOT find MSSQL_NCLI (missing: MSSQL_NCLI_LIBRARY MSSQL_NCLI_INCLUDE_DIR MSSQL_NCLI_VERSION)
Found MSSQL_ODBC: C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/SDK/Lib/x64/msodbcsql17.lib (found version "17")
Could NOT find MySQL (missing: MYSQL_LIBRARY MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Found CURL: C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/Library/lib/libcurl.lib (found version "8.1.1")
Found Iconv: C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/Library/lib/iconv.lib
Performing Test _ICONV_SECOND_ARGUMENT_IS_NOT_CONST
Performing Test _ICONV_SECOND_ARGUMENT_IS_NOT_CONST - Success
Performing Test ICONV_HAS_EXTRA_CHARSETS
Performing Test ICONV_HAS_EXTRA_CHARSETS - Success
Found LibXml2: C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/Library/lib/libxml2.lib (found version "2.10.3")
Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_DIR)
Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_LIBRARY EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR)
Failed to find XercesC (missing: XercesC_LIBRARY XercesC_INCLUDE_DIR XercesC_VERSION)
Found ZLIB: C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/Library/lib/z.lib (found version "1.2.13")
Found Deflate: C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/Library/lib/deflate.lib
Found OpenSSL: C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/Library/lib/libcrypto.lib (found version "1.1.1u") found components: SSL Crypto
Could NOT find CryptoPP (missing: CRYPTOPP_LIBRARY CRYPTOPP_TEST_KNOWNBUG CRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find PROJ (missing: PROJ_LIBRARY) (found suitable version
"6.3.2", minimum required is "6.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/modules/packages/FindPROJ.cmake:57 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
cmake/helpers/CheckDependentLibraries.cmake:378 (find_package)
gdal.cmake:265 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:246 (include)
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be unhappy with the version of libPROJ. Try installing version 9 to avoid that faulty version?

Comment: `Could NOT find PROJ (missing: PROJ_LIBRARY)` - The error is NOT about version of the PROJ package. The error is about not finding **library file** (missed variable `PROJ_LIBRARY` should be filled with the location of that file). CMake has been able to find headers files for PROJ package, and, probably, has detected the PROJ version from that files. But the library file is absent (or it has unusual name/location/unsuitable for Visual Studio/...).

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://gdal.org/development/building_from_source.html#proj), PROJ is required dependency of CDAL. How exactly have you installed it? Does this installation contain a library file(s)? If yes, then what is the exact name of such file (it should have `.lib` extension)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis: cmake depends on PROJ and swig packages

**Steps**

Download and install Anaconda.

Installed PROJ with command "conda install PROJ" in Anaconda promop.

Installed swig with command "conda install swig" in Anaconda promop.

Then, cmake works well.