# The C++ Standard Library forbids macroizing the keyword "bool". Enable warning C4005 to find the forbidden define

Tags: c++, cmake, gdal

I downloaded the GDAL 3.7.0 source code, from github.
and downloaded cmake.
Configured using VS2019 and generated the package into a folder named "gdal3.7.0-built".
double click gdal.sln and build, and get the below error. Can I have any hints about how to resolve this?

```
20>18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xkeycheck.h(55,1): fatal error C1189: #error:  The C++ Standard Library forbids macroizing the keyword "bool". Enable warning C4005 to find the forbidden define.
18>hdf5imagedataset.cpp
17>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xkeycheck.h(53,1): warning C4005: 'bool': macro redefinition
17>C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Library\include\stdbool.h(9): message : see previous definition of 'bool'
```

Comment: this question is a follow-up question of the below one.
[GDAL's CMake tooling won't accept PROJ 6.3.2 despite requiring 6.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099919/gdals-cmake-tooling-wont-accept-proj-6-3-2-despite-requiring-6-0)

[image]

Here is the error output(full version):
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IIt6MV0hsvuGkeg2AKqvXD4Wyv5KP_LQm10N-ZsZc18/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Extract a [mcve], that should help you find the issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: It's code that he found online, and doesn't compile with no changes. How in the world would he minimize that?

Comment: The `Error` window only shows error *summaries*. Please open the `Output` window and copy the *entire* error message into the question

Comment: @MooingDuck, why can't anyone extract a [mcve] from someone elses sources? Maybe I should have suggested not doing so but checking e.g. the bugtracker or perhaps filing a bug yourself, but I was just taking it as a question by someone who wants to fix/port/adapt some software.

Comment: Did you _"Enable warning C4005 to find the forbidden define."_ ? Oh, it's in `C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Library\include\stdbool.h`. Check if that header unconditionally defines `bool`. It should have a `#ifndef __cplusplus` around it.

Comment: Change the code that has `#define bool` (something-or-other) to `#define MACRO_bool`, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @Eljay The offending definition seems to be in `stdbool.h` though

Comment: @TedLyngmo: stdbool.h does contain the below code                                                              
 `#ifndef __cplusplus
#define bool  int
#define true  1
#define false 0
#else
#define bool  bool
#define false false
#define true  true
#endif`                                                                                                                          As you mentioned, what should I do to fix the errors? I mean they belongs to anaconda, I am not supposed to change them, right?

Comment: Ok, that's odd. Since it defines `bool` it probably means that `__cplusplus` is _not_ defined when that header is read - which is really odd. What C++ standard are you using when compiling?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)

Comment: Perhaps you could add `#ifndef __cplusplus`  / `#define __cplusplus 201402L`  / `#endif` before any includes to see if that makes a difference. It's not a solution, but if it makes a difference, then something seems really off.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [This was a bug in Visual Studio 16.3 (2019) Preview 1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xkeycheckh-doesnt-properly-guard-for-cplusplus-bei/689330). Please update your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: The VS version is VS ENTERPRISE 2019 16.11.30

Comment: @Rex: The bug was detected in Visual Studio 16.3 (2019) Preview 1, but your comment tells me that the bug may have already existed in older versions. The answer stands though: update to Visual Studio 16.4 or newer.

Comment: @Mooning Duck: thanks for the reminder. The errors in the print screen are found in Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, Version 16.11.30, which is newer than Visual Studio 16.4.

Comment: OH! I misread what you wrote! :O I'm so sorry!  Well... next step is to file a bug on Visual studio then?

Comment: The user has probably downloaded the wrong version if they’ve downloaded the Enterprise version for their own use and that version will cease to work after 3 months unless they’ve bought a licence so they should download the free to use version.